# How to run git commands when building a Qt App

Tags: c++, git, qt, qtquick2

**Scenario:**
I am have a Qt App with a `QtApp.pro` some C++ code in `main.cpp`. To keep this question simple, please assume that it is a blank QtQuick2 app created from the QtCreator Application wizard.

**Question:**
Is it possible to run some Qt commands in the `.pro` files or C++ code in `main.cpp`?

What if I want to run this git command `git rev-parse HEAD` from my `QtApp.pro` or `main.cpp` and embed the commit ID somewhere on my UI to show the commit ID of the release? Is it possible? How?

**Environment:**
The *Qt version* I am running is *Qt 5.9.3*
*Operating System* : MacOS High Sierra

Comment: You don't want to run `git` commands *from* your Qt App, but just when *building* that Qt App. BTW, your question could be operating system specific: on Linux, a `.pro`  file generates a `Makefile`, and `make` can run any command specified in the `Makefile`

Comment: I am running macos high sierra. updated my question with the same info. Is it possible to embed the command in pro file and access the pro file variable into an `std::string`?

Comment: See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66315563/827880

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to embed the command in pro file and access the pro file variable into an std::string?

To run command in pro file, this post, [Running a program/script from QMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612283/running-a-program-script-from-qmake), shows you how to run script in .pro. I think you can write your git command in that script.

To access the pro file variable into an std::string.
you can transfer the file variable by `-D` option of gcc, which you can define it with QMAKE_CFLAGS in .pro file. this post, [How to define a string literal in gcc command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410976/how-to-define-a-string-literal-in-gcc-command-line) shows you how to use `-D` option.

Comment: @Game_Of_Threads,  By the way, I guess you are trying to do something like this one, [qmake pre-build step before ANY compilation
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864689/qmake-pre-build-step-before-any-compilation) .   :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to think separately of [build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build) time (includes compile-time) and [run time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_(program_lifecycle_phase)). In general (think of some [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) scenario, or just of a Qt application [deployed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_deployment) on other computers) that could happen on different machines and on different days.

At run time, you could use [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) to run some [`git`](http://git-scm.com/) command (or whatever program or script you need to run). Of course, you need `git` to be installed, and perhaps your [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) tree to be available at run time (on a [deployed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_deployment) and installed Qt application, that might not be the case by default; for example most Qt applications on my Linux distribution are not [installed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installation_(computer_programs)) with their source code tree).

At build time, on Unix-like machines, a `.pro` Qt project file is generating a [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) which is used by [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) for build. That `Makefile` could contain `git` commands. See `_timestamp.c` target of this [`Makefile`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/Makefile#L93) (not using Qt so hand-written, not generated by `qmake`) as an example; it contains details about the current git commit.

How to configure [`qmake`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html) to generate custom commands in the  `Makefile` is a different question; you might add [custom targets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html).

Comment: could you cite and example using the `QProcess` way? the `QProcess` way of running a git command looks like an easier approach

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) ? But I insist: by default the source files are not available, because you would deploy your Qt application on other machines without transmitting its source files.